# What is the algorithm for the optimal decoder in a quantum erasure channel?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, error-correction, quantum-operation, stabilizer-code

I'm reading this paper : [Holographic Quantum Error Correcting Codes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.06472) and on page 3 they describe an optimal decoder for erasure channel.

The
description is for CSS codes but they claim that "it is straightforwardly adapted to any stabiliser
code". I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Is anyone familiar with or has a reference for the algorithm for the optimal decoder in quantum erasure channel? Also is there any software/package that has it implemented?